# How to run a templated Cloud Dataflow job in a Shielded VMs on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

According to the [public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#dataflow-shielded-vm) it is possible to run a Cloud Dataflow job in Shielded VMs on GCP.

For a non-templated job, like described in the [Quick Start manual for Java](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/create-pipeline-java) that can be achieved by submitting the `--dataflowServiceOptions=enable_secure_boot` flag as following:

```
mvn -Pdataflow-runner compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=org.apache.beam.examples.WordCount -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties -Dexec.args="--project=${PROJECT_ID} \
--gcpTempLocation=gs://${BUCKET_NAME}/temp/ \
--output=gs://${BUCKET_NAME}/output \
--runner=DataflowRunner \
--region=${REGION} \
--dataflowServiceOptions=enable_secure_boot"
```

But when using a templated job, e.g. started using gcloud or Terraform:

```
gcloud dataflow jobs run word-count --gcs-location gs://dataflow-templates-europe-west3/latest/Word_Count --region ${REGION} --staging-location gs://${BUCKET_NAME}/temp --parameters inputFile=gs://${BUCKET_NAME}/sample.txt,output=gs://${BUCKET_NAME}/sample-output
```

The VM that gets started is not Shielded (when looking at its "Secure Boot" flag at runtime).

How can I run a templated Dataflow job in a Shielded VM on GCP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### gcloud

To deploy the Dataflow job on shielded VMs, the [`additional-experiments`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataflow/jobs/run#:%7E:text=OPTIONAL%20FLAGS-,%2D%2Dadditional%2Dexperiments,-%3D%5BADDITIONAL_EXPERIMENTS%2C%E2%80%A6%5D) flag has to be set to `enable_secure_boot`. I tested this out and was able to see that the secure boot was on during the job runtime.

```
gcloud dataflow jobs run word-count-on-shielded-vm-from-gcloud --project=project-id \
--gcs-location gs://dataflow-templates-europe-west3/latest/Word_Count \
--region us-central1 --staging-location gs://bucket-name/temp \
--parameters inputFile=gs://apache-beam-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt,output=gs://bucket-name/sample-output \
--additional-experiments=enable_secure_boot
```

---

### Terraform

By adding the [`additional_experiments`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/dataflow_job#additional_experiments) argument with `enable_secure_boot` to the `google_dataflow_job` resource, the Dataflow job can be deployed on shielded VMs.

```
resource "google_dataflow_job" "word_count_job" {
  name              = "sample-dataflow-wordcount-job"
  template_gcs_path = "gs://dataflow-templates-europe-west3/latest/Word_Count"
  temp_gcs_location = "${google_storage_bucket.bucket.url}/temp"
  parameters = {
    inputFile = "${google_storage_bucket.bucket.url}/input_file.txt",
    output = "${google_storage_bucket.bucket.url}/word_count.txt"
  }
  additional_experiments = [
    "enable_secure_boot"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sending update since I've recently ran into this myself. Shielded VMs no longer need to be explicitly mentioned when deploying Dataflow jobs. The Dataflow service as of June 1, 2022 automatically deploys shielded VMs now.

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#dataflow-shielded-vm